# Google Identity Toolkit add third-party authentication

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

I'm looking for a way to add social sign-in to our website and I found the Google Identity Toolkit solution.

It looks great and easy to set-up, however I am wondering if there is a way to customize this Toolkit in order to add other third-party authentication provider (like Linkedin or Twitter)

I have found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-identity-toolkit/CWJaq4D2Wlw) which was talking of adding it to the v3, but apparently there is still nothing available?

Comment: I'm in the same path, trying to find how to implement it in my ASP.NET C# webapp

Comment: Finally I decided to go using Pac4J for more flexibility (http://www.pac4j.org/)

I'm sorry @IdanShechter, I don't know any equivalent in C#. I hope you'll find something!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Restapi Identity Toolkit.

[verifyAssertion](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/reference/relyingparty/verifyAssertion)

So you can log in with your account: `Google`, `Facebook`, `Twitter`, `Github`.
 For example login with google will look like this:

POST ...`verifyAssertion?key={{server_key}}`

with body:

```
{
  "postBody": "id_token=token_value&providerId=google.com",
  "requestUri": "http://localhost",
  "returnIdpCredential": true,
  "returnSecureToken": true
}
```

where `providerId` is a provider type and `id_token` is a `oauth2` token of google account in this case